# Modifying a variable within an imported function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say we had two files:

File1.py

```
X = 4
def f():
    print(X)
```

File2.py

```
from File1 import f
X = 10
f()    
# prints 4
```

How can we change the `X` inside of the function `f`?

Comment: give `X` as an argument of `f()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to export a function that does the job:

File1:

```
X = 4
def setX(newValue):
    global X
    X = newValue
def f():
        print(X)
```

File2

```
from File1 import f
from File1 import setX
setX(10)
f()
```

This solution exports a function to set the value from outside File1; you simply call it to modify the variable

---

Or a more generic version:

```
def set_global(name, value):
    globals()[name] = value
```

File2:

```
set_global('X', 10)
f() #prints 10
```

Comment: Yep, that's a very good answer. 
Just need to find a way now to make `setX` more generic, and take any argument (not just `X`).

Comment: Added the generic version.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `X` as an argument to `f()` and set `X` in the function in the case that no value is passed.

File1.py

```
def f(X=4):
    print(X)
```

File2.py

```
from File1 import f
f(10)    
# prints 10
```

Comment: thanks, but I purposefully didn't put X as an argument as my use case (patching) can't be changed.